# adding an app to battery saver programmatically when the app is installed

Tags: android, battery, battery-saver

i developed an Android application, it contains so much background services and it uses Medias unfortunately this app is draining the battery life fast
i search the web but i didn't reach a good solution, i'm asking if possible how to put the app programmatically in battery saver 
it's a solution at least but i want that programmatically
when the app is installed.

please give me some suggestions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> how to put the app programmatically in battery saver

That is not possible, sorry, at least in terms of the standard battery optimization list on Android 6.0+. If it were, then app app developers would add their apps to the list, and there would be no point in having the battery optimization list.